# asp.net store data best way

Tags: asp.net, store

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
```

what way is the best:
1)

```
Session["SerializedList"] = myList;
```

or
2)

```
string serializedList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myList);
Session["SerializedList"] = serializedList;

Session["SerializedList"] = myList;
```

Comment: You're overriding the assignment of the JSON encoded list with the original list! Is that a typo? Either way, I would stick with the first and let ASP.NET worry about serialization and deserialization of data in the session as it's likely way more efficient than doing it yourself everywhere you need it with JSON

Comment: Define "best" .